# How to call dynamic crm 2016 rest api from javascript?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to create lead in dynamic crm from my website. My website is build using HTML as this is a static site. I need to call dynamic crm (setup on premises) api from contact us page to submit data in dynamic crm.

Please suggest me a right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK has lots of helpful information, have you looked at it?  Here's a start:

[Authenticating to CRM from JS using adal.js](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595799.aspx)

[Perform operations using the Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607901.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Polshgiant. but adal.js required an azure account first. can we have any option without this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code we use to submit entries from webpage to CRM. Hope this helps:

```js
function CreateWebLeadInCRM(SourceCampaignName, Email, MobilePhone, FirstName, LastName, CompanyName){
var webLead = new Object();

//Add Source Campaing name
if(SourceCampaignName != null)
    webLead.sof_sourcecampaign = SourceCampaignName;
//Add Email
if(Email != null)
    webLead.sof_Email = Email;
//Add Mobile phone
if(MobilePhone != null)
    webLead.sof_MobilePhone = MobilePhone;
//Add First name
if(FirstName != null)
    webLead.sof_FirstName = FirstName;
//Add Last name
if(LastName != null)
    webLead.sof_LastName = LastName;
//Add Company name
if(CompanyName != null)
    webLead.sof_CompanyName = CompanyName;


var jsonwebLead = JSON.stringify(webLead);
var createwebLeadReq = new XMLHttpRequest();    
createwebLeadReq.open("POST", "http://SERVER/ORG/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/sof_webleadSet", true, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
createwebLeadReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
createwebLeadReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
createwebLeadReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
    createwebLeadReqCallBack(this);
};
createwebLeadReq.send(jsonwebLead);
```

Ugly thing about this approach is that you have to save your password inside your javascript function, which is not really safe approach.. On the other hand you should only allow this user to insert entries to only one custom table without possibility to do anything else inside your CRM. This way you could manage what happens if you get spammed by the bots.

Comment: Thanks Andrius. Yes there is a big security risk. Anyone can see my credentials in web page. Is there any other approach except Azure Authentication?